# Should System be explicitly imported in a Xamarin.Android class file?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

**I'm pruning out unnecessary `using` directives, and am not sure if I should leave**

```
using System;
```

**in all my files or not?**

In a **Xamarin.Android** Visual Studio class file, this directive
 imports the namespace defined in

*...\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll*

However, I have many files that are not *explicitly* using any types from there (which can be indicated by the faded/grayed syntax highlighting). However, it is my understanding that **.NET** primitives are aliases that the compiler substitutes for types within the `System` namespace (`int` <=> `System.Int32`), so I'm not sure if this could potentially cause any issues. The compiler never throws any kind of ambiguity error if omitted (between **.NET System** and **Xamarin System**), and my testing so far hasn't resulted in any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask that question because you have a misunderstanding between the *using directive* and *referenced assemblies*.

`using` does not *reference* any assembly.

The **References** added to your project do (s. the "References" node in the Solution Explorer, or "Dependencies" in .NET Core projects), hence their name, *References*.

`using` only allows you to shortcut *using* namespaces or types available in the **previously separately referenced** assemblies in your code, e.g. writing `Console.WriteLine()` instead of `System.Console.WriteLine()`.

You may ask why this differentation has been made in the first case. Well, one issue would be that if you had two assemblies defining types with the same name (let's say, some `XBox` related assembly also providing a `Console` type) and you *would* also reference the assemblies with the `using` directive as you were thinking, there'd be no way to differ between `System.Console` or `XBox.Console` in code, as there are now two `Console` types accessible at the "same time".

To come back to reality, you can remove any `using` directives which are grayed out with **absolutely no impact on how your application behaves** as the references to the assemblies will still stay intact (nothing in the "References" node in your Solution Explorer will have changed), and so your application will still be able to access the types defined in `System` - just *you* won't be able to use them like `Int32` instead of `System.Int32` for example.

Now the joke about the primitive types is that C# provides *keywords* to shortcut those types like `Int32` at *any* time (no matter if you have `using System;` on top of your file or not) by writing simply `int`, or `bool` for `System.Boolean`, and so on. That's the reason why your directive is grayed out, because you used those primitive types (if at all) through their *keyword*. Replace one `int` with the actual type name `Int32` and you'll see the directive not being grayed out anymore.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. Visual Studio doesn't have it's own "hard coded" reference to the "normal" .NET System.dll to resolve the primitives to, it's going to use whatever is in References (Xamarin projects use their own version of System.dll)?

Comment: Will the linker still include assemblies for "grayed out" using directives?

Comment: Yeah, if you remove the `System` reference in the solution explorer, most of your stuff will stop working, so you should keep it. The `using` directives have no effect on the assemblies, nor on what the "linker" sees - it also only sees the References in your solution explorer. `using` directives only determine in which namespaces the _compiler_ looks for the types you use inside your code files.

Comment: So as part of the first pass during static analysis the compiler probably substitutes all type references to their absolute "path's", like with primitives. I recall in c++ it was  possible to `include` entire libraries, but I think you could also just `include` a header file as well, which seems to align better with `using`.

Comment: Yes to your assumption, the compiler "gets the absolute paths" (fully qualified type names) when compiling. `using` is really more like `using namespace` in C++, but not as frowned upon as in C++, actually quite the opposite, use it wherever possible to keep your code clean and "see sharp".

Answer (score 0):

If it's greyed out then yup, delete it. You don't need it for primitive types, only for objects inside that namespace such as `DateTime` or `Guid`.

Using directives have nothing to do with what assemblies are in use, only to help the compiler resolve types that are not qualified with namespaces. Any greyed out using can be deleted.

Comment: using directives will only resolve referenced assemblies.

Comment: Yes, but what I meant was they don't control it - so if you don't have a using directive it will still use the assembly and be able to resolve the types

Comment: @samusarin What you mean is the References node in the Solution Explorer, not the using directives in your code files.

Comment: @JimBobBennett For built-in primitives only though, right?

Comment: @RayKoopa Yeah the `using` directive that references the *System* assembly in the *References* node.

Comment: @samusarin You still misunderstood what `using` does by saying that it "references" the assembly; take some time and s. my answer below; I hope it can help your confusion.

Comment: @RayKoopa Oh my bad, I meant *importing* not *referencing*.